# I can ping server on a port that is not in my vlan, or any vlan on a netgear JGS524PE switch. Why?

Tags: networking, vlan, 802.1q

I have a Netgear JGS524PE 24-Port switch.

I want my pc on port 14 to be able to connect to port 22, 23, get dns and dhcp from port 17 and internet through port 24

I want my room mate to get dns, dhcp, and internet but not access any other ports

I want ports 1-13 to get dns, dhcp, and internet but not connect to other ports

I am confused on port 24 and 17. Do I put that in each VLAN? If it's not in each VLAN, then then how will VLAN2 and VLAN3 get internet?

- VLAN1 ports: 1-13, 17, 24 (24 is Tagged)
- VLAN2 ports: 21, 17, 24
- VLAN3 ports: 14, 17, 22, 23, 24

Set me straight please.
[image: Network Diagram]

Comment: It helps a lot of you don't think (and make diagrams) in terms of ports, but in terms of **network segments**. In particular, if "port 24" is part of multiple network segments, that means all segments are bridged. So design your network around the segments, no matter if those are VLANs or not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the router's port needs to be a member of all VLANs. The DHCP server should typically be in all VLANs too (unless you have the router act as a *DHCP relay*). The DNS server doesn't need to be.

However, the router and the server must *themselves* understand VLANs – i.e. you need to configure virtual interfaces for each tagged VLAN that they're a member of. If your router is not capable of using 802.1Q VLANs, then you generally cannot use VLANs with it (unless you make a separate physical connection for each VLAN).

Also note that a port cannot have more than one 'untagged' VLAN – if you do this, the router won't be able to distinguish which virtual interface the packet belongs to; and when it needs to send a reply back, it won't be able to tell the switch which VLAN to put the packets in. Many switches won't actually allow you to configure multiple untagged VLANs for the same port.

So an example configuration would look like:

- Switch:

  - VLAN 1: Ports [...], 17 (untagged), [...]
  - VLAN 2: Ports [...], 17 (tagged), [...]
  - VLAN 3: Ports [...], 17 (tagged), [...]
- Server on port 17:

  - Physical interface `eth0` (default/native/untagged VLAN): `192.168.1.67/24`
  - Virtual interface `eth0.2` (tagged VLAN 2): `192.168.2.67/24`
  - Virtual interface `eth0.3` (tagged VLAN 3): `192.168.3.67/24`

(Just to be clear, each VLAN must have its own IP subnet.)

Your router will handle not only Internet access, but inter-VLAN access as well, therefore access *between* VLANs is controlled by your router's firewall and not by switch configuration. If you don't want VLAN1 to be able to talk to VLAN2, you have to add a firewall rule saying so.